# Write soap XML using XOM

Tags: android, xml, xom

I'm trying to write a soap mesage with:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

using [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/).

I'm creating the element using

```
Element soap = new Element("soap:Envelope", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
```

but I don't know how to add the xmlns:xsi and xmln:xsd attributes. Using

```
Attribute xsi = new Attribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

return the following error

```
Attribute objects are not used to represent namespace declarations
```

So how can I add these attributes?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use XOM?   Could you write the soap/xml out yourself and send it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm going to do...

Answer (score 0):

XOM and other tree-based packages should automatically add required namespace declarations, 
based on namespace URIs (and possibly prefixes) you define for your elements and attributes.
So why are you trying to add them explicitly? Does that not work?